# Expected Score in a Coin Flipping Game

Tags: probability

Suppose I have two Coins.

There is a selection probability associated with each coin:

- Coin 1: There is a $p_1$ probability of selecting Coin 1
- Coin 2: There is a $1-p_1$ probability of selecting Coin 2

For each of these coins, we know the probability of success:

- Coin 1: Probability of Heads is $p_2$ and Probability of Tails is $1-p_2$
- Coin 2: Probability of Heads is $p_3$ and Probability of Tails is $1-p_3$

There are "scores" associated with coin:

- Coin 1: When Heads, Score = $z_1$ . When tails, Score = $z_2$
- Coin 2: When Heads, Score = $z_3$. When tails, Score = $z_4$

Given this information, suppose I play a game where I select a coin, flip the coin, calculate my score - then repeat this process 100 times.

**My Question:**

- After playing this game 100 times, what can I expect my average score to be?
- After playing this game 100 times, what can I expect the variance of my score to be?

Here is my attempt to answer this:

**Part 1:** On the first turn, my expected score is:

$$E_1 = (p_1p_2z_1) + p_1(1-p_2)z_2  + (1-p_1)(p_3)z_3 + (1-p_1)(1-p_3)z_4 $$

As nothing changes from flip to flip, my expected score after 100 turns is:

$$E_{100} = 100 * [(p_1p_2z_1) + p_1(1-p_2)z_2  + (1-p_1)(p_3)z_3 + (1-p_1)(1-p_3)z_4 ]$$

**Part 2:** Now, I can consider the "squared expected score" after 1 turn:

- $z_1^2$ with probability $p_1p_2$
- $z_2^2$ with probability $p_1(1-p_2)$
- $z_3^2$ with probability $(1-p_1)p_3$
- $z_4^2$ with probability $(1-p_1)(1-p_3)$

Thus, the total "squared expected score" after 1 turn can be written as:

$$E_{1}^2 = z_1^2 *p_1p_2 + z_2^2*p_1(1-p_2) + z_3^2*(1-p_1)p_3 + z_4^2*(1-p_1)(1-p_3)$$

And after 100 turns, the total "squared expected score" after 1 turn can be written as:

$$E_{100}^2 = 100 * E_{1}^2 $$

$$ E_{100}^2 = 100 * [z_1^2 *p_1p_2 + z_2^2*p_1(1-p_2) + z_3^2*(1-p_1)p_3 + z_4^2*(1-p_1)(1-p_3)]$$

Thus, from first principles - the Variance of the Score after 100 turns can be written as:

$$Var_{100} =  E_{100}^2 - (E_{100})^2$$

**Can someone please tell me if my analysis is correct?**

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is correct.